# regex for markdown validator

Tags: python, regex, markdown

I've been developing a Telegram bot with CMS with Markdown support. The tags supported are

````
*bold text*
_italic text_
`inline fixed-width code`
```text
pre-formatted fixed-width code block
```
````

the problem is when there is, say, an opening `*` tag and no closing `*` tag, the bot API breaks and refuses to send the message.

I'm not that much into regex, but is there a way to build a regex that validates all said tags when the message is constructed? or is there a ready-made markdown validator?

I tried python `markdown` lib, meaning to catch an exception from it, but it doesnt break when the tags are broken, it just leaves the incorrect tags untouched.

Comment: FYI, your text is _not_ using standard Markdown syntax. In Markdown `*this is emphasized*` (using `<em>`, just like `_this is_`, which is usually rendered in italics). To get `<strong>` (which typically renders in bold) you need to use `**two asterisks**` or `__two underscores__`. https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#em

Answer (score 0):

To check if the line starts and ends with '*' try regex pattern

```
> ^\*.*\*$
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach might suit your needs:

```
import re
teststring="*hello*?Q@*()@(UE) World?@(EI)@EN *"
results=re.findall("^[*].*[*]$",teststring)
if not len(results)==1:
    raise Exception
```

It assumes that a line starts with * and ends with *.
The _ and ' cases would follow a similar approach.
Because the ''' case includes newlines, use the DOTALL flag:

```
re.findall("^[']{3}.*[']{3}$",teststring, re.DOTALL)
```